Read existing files in dir on SD-Card and create file with next bigger number
I have a SD-card attached to an ESP32C3. It's mounted and I can write to it. My goal is to automatically create a file with the next bigger number. In the case below I expect it to create a file named FILE_6.LOG:
FILE_0.LOG
FILE_4.LOG
FILE_5.LOG

This is how I loop through the directory for all existing files and decide which number goes into the filename:
#define MOUNT_POINT "/sdcard"
#define MAX_FILENAME_LENGTH 256
char next_filename[MAX_FILENAME_LENGTH];

DIR* dir;
struct dirent* entry;
int max_number = 0;

dir = opendir(MOUNT_POINT);

while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
    int current_number;
    if (sscanf(entry->d_name, "FILE_%d.LOG", &current_number) == 1) {
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Extracted number: %d , Max number: %d", current_number, max_number);
        if (current_number > max_number) {
            max_number = current_number;
        }
    }
}

closedir(dir);

int new_number = max_number + 1;
ESP_LOGI(TAG, "%d %d", max_number, new_number);

snprintf(next_filename, MAX_FILENAME_LENGTH, "%s/FILE_%d.LOG", MOUNT_POINT, new_number);

FILE* file = fopen(next_filename, "w");
if (file == NULL) {
    ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Failed to create file: %s\n", next_filename);
    return;
}

fprintf(file, "NEW LOG %d\n", new_number);
fclose(file);

It works as expected, but on 10 it fails to create the file?!
...
I (405) CL: Extracted number: 1 , Max number: 0
I (415) CL: Extracted number: 2 , Max number: 1
I (415) CL: Extracted number: 3 , Max number: 2
I (425) CL: Extracted number: 4 , Max number: 3
I (425) CL: Extracted number: 5 , Max number: 4
I (435) CL: Extracted number: 6 , Max number: 5
I (435) CL: Extracted number: 7 , Max number: 6
I (445) CL: Extracted number: 8 , Max number: 7
I (445) CL: Extracted number: 9 , Max number: 8
I (455) CL: 9 10
E (455) CL: Failed to create file: /sdcard/FILE_10.LOG

Why is that? The filesystem is FAT and I basically used this sd_card_example_main.c example.

What is the reason text from strerror(errno)?

your program may not have write permissions to the SD card...

@WeatherVane Like this? ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Failed to create file: %s - %s\n", next_filename, strerror(errno));? - I get Invalid argument.

And errno is 22.
